# Exterior point of $S=(1,2)\cap \mathbb{Q}$

Tags: general-topology

Let $S=(1,2)\cap \mathbb{Q}$ then what is the set of all boundary points of $S?$

**Define** I know that for any subset $S \subset \mathbb{R}$ then $int(S)\cup ext(S)\cup boundary(S) =\mathbb{R}$
and
the exterior of any subset S of real numbers is the interior of the complement of S.
and our question $int(S)=\phi$ and $ext(S)=(-\infty,1)\cup(2,\infty)$ and $boundary(S)=[1,2].$

I put the question here to check/verify the solution to this kind of problem is correct or not.
Please just correct me if I'm wrong somewhere.

My second doubt is,
Let $A$ and $B$ be any two subset of $\mathbb{R}$ then

$A\cup B=\{x \mid x\in A \mbox{ or } x\in B\}$ and $A+B=\{a+b \mid  a\in A  \mbox{ and } b\in B\}$ Is there any relation between $A\cup B$ and $A+B$?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You found the boundary correctly. There is no inclusion between $A+B$ and $A\cup B$ in general. $A\cup B \subseteq A+B$ if $0 \in A\cap B$.

Answer (score 1):

Your first solution is correct.

For the second doubt in general there is no particular relation between $A\cup B$ and $A+B$.

If $0\in A$ then $B\subset A+B$ , if $0\in B$ then $A\subset A+B$ and if $0\in A \cap B$ then $A\cup B\subset A+B$

Comment: we know $\mathbb{R}=\mathbb{Q} \cup \mathbb{Q^c}$ but i think $\mathbb{Q} + \mathbb{Q^c}$ is contains all irrational but not rationals. right?

Comment: Correct! that is because zero is not irrational. Infact, $\mathbb{Q}+\mathbb{Q}^c$ do not contain any rational number. 

$\mathbb{Q}+\mathbb{Q}^c$ is nothing but set of all irrational numbers.